# WPF XAML datatrigger fails to fire after programmatically changing property value C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this code in my xaml which says to color my button when I hover my mouse and click my mouse over the button.

```
<Border x:Class="DatasetGrid.RowHeaderButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" MinWidth="30" Width="Auto">
<Border.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtOverBrush" Color="#53C3D5" Opacity="0.2"></SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtPressedBrush" Color="#53C3D5" Opacity="0.5"></SolidColorBrush>
</Border.Resources>
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtOverBrush}"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseDown, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtPressedBrush}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
</Border>
```

This works all well and good, but I find that as soon as I change the Background color in code behind, the above MouseOver and MouseDown triggers don't fire anymore.

```
RowHeaderButton rhb = RowHeadersColumn.VisibleRowHeaders[cell.CellInfo.RowIndex];
rhb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 83, 195, 213));
```

I'm quite new to WPF so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Edit:

So to give some more information, my control above is a RowHeaderButton, i.e the row header to a grid. Each row in the grid has it's own row header button. So when the user hovers over or clicks it, it should change from white to the specified SolidColorBrush above.

In the code behind of another control, DataGrid.xaml.cs, I have the below code (simplified) which will change the color of the row header when when a cell in the same row of the grid is selected or not.

```
void UpdateSelectedCells() {            

    foreach (Cell cell in VisibleColumns.SelectMany(c => c.VisibleCells))
        {
            int cellRowIndex = cell.CellInfo.RowIndex;
            cell.IsSelected = SelectedCells.Contains(cell.CellInfo);

            foreach (RowHeaderButton rhb in RowHeadersColumn.VisibleRowHeaders)
            {
                int rowHeaderIndex = Convert.ToInt16(rhb._default.Text) - 1;

                if (cellRowIndex == rowHeaderIndex)
                {
                    if (cell.IsSelected)
                    {
                        rhb.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, 83, 195, 213));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool rowselected = false;

                        //need to check if any other cell in the row is selected, if not then color row header white
                        foreach (CellInfo celll in SelectedCells)
                        {

                            if (celll.RowIndex == cellRowIndex)
                            {
                                rowselected = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (rowselected == false)
                            rhb.Background = Brushes.White;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I don't have a ViewModel for this.

Comment: If you create a simple ViewModel the code will get better, easier to change GUI without directly changing the GUI elements, but changing the properties that are Binded with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triggers are firing, but their setters are being overridden.

This is due to [Dependency Property Value Precendence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence). If the `Background` property is set programmatically or as an attribute in the XAML, that value will override anything value any style setter gives it. In general, this is desirable behavior: You want to be able to override what the style does on an individual control.

The solution to this is to do all of your background brush changes in style triggers. Your code behind must have some reason for setting the background brush when it does. Whatever that is, find a way to do it with a trigger. Set a property on the viewmodel and write a trigger on that property.

If you need help translating that high level abstraction into your own code, please share enough code for me to understand why and where the codebehind is setting the Background, and what (if anything) you have for a viewmodel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes sense now. I'll make an edit to my code above so it might be easier fr you to understand what im doing/trying to acheive.

Comment: I've added a little more info in the main post. I don't use a view model, the code behind is for the DataGrid.xaml.cs while the above XAML is in the RowHeaderButton.xaml

Comment: @nerdalert Are you just coloring the row header cell if there is *any* selected cell in that row?

Comment: Yes, I color the row header if any cell in the row is selected. It indicates that the row is in focus. I should probably simplify the code further, I also have code there to color column headers so it may be confusing. That code isn't necessary for this case.

Comment: I've simplified the code further to only include row header coloring.

Comment: @nerdalert Thanks. What's the full context for the Border XAML you shared? Is that in the template for the row headers or something?

Comment: That's from the row header designer, I updated the xaml to show the full code. Note that there is code behind for this xaml which i haven't shared. I don't know if it's necessary?

Comment: I have some dependancy properties defined in the code behind of the rowheaderbutton, maybe I can create the property here?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your code. Is `RowHeaderButton` your own class that you wrote? Are you using a regular WPF DataGrid? Is `RowHeaderButton` a visual child (or grandchild etc.) of a DataGridRow?

Comment: Yes RowHeaderButton is my own class. Also the DataGrid is a custom written one. In any case, I believe I solved the issue by taking into account your initial advice to create a new property for whether a cell is selected, and color the row based on it

Comment: @nerdalert Excellent. While it's true that you'd be better off using MVVM, it's not at all relevant to this particular problem -- this is pure UI/control/dependency property stuff.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and for trying to understand my code!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by creating a new Dependancy Property and binding it to a data trigger.

```
public bool IsCellSelected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsCellSelectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsCellSelectedProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCellSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsCellSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(RowHeaderButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

In my xaml I have:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCellSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtPressedBrush}"></Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

And in my code behind I set the value using:

```
RowHeaderButton rhb = RowHeadersColumn.VisibleRowHeaders[cell.CellInfo.RowIndex];
rhb.IsCellSelected = true; //or false
```

Now my button hover and button click events are not overridden.